# Restrict folder sharing over cygwin sshd

Tags: cygwin

I recently installed a SSH server on my Windows 7 PC and created a separate user account for this. When i logged in using SSH, i could access all the windows directories.

> /cygdrive/c 
>   /cygdrive/d 
>   /cygdrive/e

**How do i prevent this user from accessing all the win directories other than its home directory under cygwin /home/chuck/ ?**

Preferably i do not want the user to even view /cygdrive when the user types "mount".
Is there a easy way to do this?
I want to later allow remote users to log on to this machine and avoid messing up other things.
I know i can setup a separate machine but this is a plan for later.

Comment: Needs to be moved to superuser

Comment: the user is running as an administrator on the windows machine if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about Cygwin but in Unix in general you could use the [chroot](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot).

Comment: Try to follow something like:

http://www.howtoforge.com/chroot_ssh_sftp_debian_etch

Answer (score 0):

try changing the group of the ssh_user_name to Guest, then specifically allow rwx perms for the Guest group through the security tab in Windows. I have not tried this before, which I am going to try soon. This should be easier than denying access to each drive by adding the ssh_user_name, which is highly inefficient if you have many drives like I do.

The reason why i chose guest is because by default it is denied all access, which makes it easier to specifically choose which drive you want the ssh_user_name to have access to.

Comment: I tried this and it kinda worked for me initially but later on when i rebooted my PC, all went back to the way it was. And this time when i tried to set the restriction, it was of no use...i could still browse through all the directories...